# python list concatenation efficiency

Tags: python, list

What is the most efficient way to concatenate two lists `list_a` and `list_b` when:

- `list_b` items have to be placed before `list_a` items
- the result must be placed in `list_a`

I have 4 possibilities in mind:

```
# 1
list_a = list_b + list_a

# 2
for item in list_b:
    list_a.insert(0, item)

# 3
for item in self.list_a:
    list_b.append(item)
list_a = list_b

# 4
list_a[0:0] = list_b
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do this often or with very large data, there are better data structures (a simple one: store all your lists reversed).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's a graph of how the timings used in the [answer of BigYellowCactus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12088237/) develop as the length of the lists increase. The vertical axis is the time required to initialize both lists and insert one in front of the other, in usec. The horizontal axis is the number of items in the lists.

[image: Asymptotic behaviour of the possibilities]

**t1**:

```
list_a = list_b + list_a
```

**t2**:

```
for item in list_b:
    list_a.insert(0, item)
```

**t3**:

```
for item in list_a:
    list_b.append(item)
list_a = list_b
```

**t4**:

```
list_a[0:0] = list_b
```

Comment: I know this question was asked long ago, I do wonder: If I am just adding listb to lista....so a then b...does this scenario still hold? Or are there even more efficient ways to add n lists into 1 list?

Comment: This chart is wrong. It times creating `list_a`, which absolutely dominates the run time of the two fastest methods, `list_a = list_b + list_a` and `list_a[0:0] = list_b`

Answer (score 9):

Given that

```
list_a = list_b + list_a
```

works for your purposes, it follows that you don't actually need the `list_a` object itself to store all the data in `list_a` - you just need it *called* `list_a` (ie, you don't have, or don't care about, any other variables you have floating around that might refer to that same list).

If you also happen not to care about it being exactly a list, but only about it being iterable, then you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
list_a = itertools.chain(list_b, list_a)
```

If you *do* care about some list things, you could construct a similar type of thing to `chain` that behaves like a list - something like:

```
class ListChain(list):
    def __init__(self, *lists):
        self._lists = lists

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain.from_iterable(self._lists)

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(len(l) for l in self._lists)

    def append(self, item):
        self._lists[-1].append(item)

    def extend(self, iterable):
        self._lists.append(list(iterable))

    def __getitem__(self, item):
       for l in self._lists:
           if item < len(l):
              return l[item]
           item -= len(l)
       else:
          raise IndexError
```

etc. This would take a lot of effort (possibly more than its worth) for this to work in all cases - eg, handling slices and negative indexes comes to mind. But for very simple cases, this approach can avoid a lot of copying list contents around.

Comment: Insightful answer! But not useful in my case. `list_a` is from a 3rdParty module that I don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 6):

You can assign list_b to a slice, which happens to be empty but at the start of list_a:

```
list_a[0:0] = list_b
```

This is the fastest way to insert a list into another list, at any position.

Comment: how to use this method to append to end of list

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar: use `list.extend()` to add to the end of a list. You can use `list_a[len(list_a):len(list_a)]` to assign to the end too, but that's much more tedious to have to write, read and execute.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) just makes a generator, so if you can get away with using a generator instead of a list, it's constant time to generate but you pay the cost when you access each element. Otherwise `list_a[0:0] = list_b` is about 6 times faster than `list_a = list_b + list_a`

I think that `list_a = list_b + list_a` is the most readable choice and it's already pretty fast.

The two methods that you mentioned that use `append()` in a `for` loop are unusably slow so I didn't bother including them.

---

Ran with Python 3.7.5 `[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin` on a 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 with 16 GB of 2133 MHz LPDDR3 RAM using the following code:

```
from timeit import timeit
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_data_points = 1000
step = 10
methods = [
    # ordered from slowest to fastest to make the key easier to read
    # """for item in list_a: list_b.append(item); list_a = list_b""",
    # """for item in list_b: list_a.insert(0, item)""",
    # "list_a = list(itertools.chain(list_b, list_a))",
    "list_a = list_b + list_a",
    "list_a[0:0] = list_b",
    "list_a = itertools.chain(list_b, list_a)",
]

x = list(range(0, num_data_points * step, step))
y = [[] for _ in methods]
for i in x:
    list_a = list(range(i))
    list_b = list(range(i))
    random.shuffle(list_a)
    random.shuffle(list_b)
    setup = f"list_a = {list_a}; list_b = {list_b}"
    for method_index, method in enumerate(methods):
        y[method_index].append(timeit(method, setup=setup, number=30))
    print(i, "out of", num_data_points * step)

ax = plt.axes()
for method_index, method in enumerate(methods):
    ax.plot(x, y[method_index], label=method)
ax.set(xlabel="number of elements in both lists", ylabel="time (s) (lower is better)")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I posted this answer because the timings in the accepted answer are wrong, the creation of the lists shouldn't be part of the timings.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
list_a[0:0] = list_b
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)?

```
import timeit

create_data = """\
list_a = range(10)
list_b = range(10)
"""

t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt=create_data + """\
list_a = list_b + list_a
""")

t2 = timeit.Timer(create_data + """\
for item in list_b:
    list_a.insert(0, item)
""")

t3 = timeit.Timer(create_data + """\
for item in list_a:
    list_b.append(item)
list_a = list_b
""")

t4 = timeit.Timer(create_data + """\
list_a[0:0] = list_b
""")

for i, t in enumerate([t1,t2,t3,t4]):
    print i, "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
```

**Result:**

> 0 0.73 usec/pass
>   1 2.79 usec/pass
>   2 1.66 usec/pass
>   3 0.77 usec/pass

Comment: You are now also timing the list creation. Better move that out to the setup instead of the timed portion. But since you have to reset the inputs every time again anyway that prolly won't make much difference..