# Accelerating list concatenation in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm running the following code:

```
x = []
for i in c:
    x = x+i
```

The result has about 50-100 million elements.

This takes several minutes to run on my PC. How can I accelerate this?

Comment: sum(c) is definitely better code, I hadn't thought of that. Still seems to be slow though.

Comment: But *what is `c`*? Is it a list, NumPy array, tuple or something else?

Comment: It's a list (though I could cast it to something else)

Comment: A list of lists? A list of tuples? A list of floats? Objects? Can we see a sample?

Comment: No `sum` is **not better code**. Use `.extend` to concatenate in a loop, that will have amoratized constant time behavior instead of quadratic. Or use `+=` (which calls extend). Just plain list concatenation, `+` is O(A+B), so to concatenate a bunch of small lists, this creates quadratic time complexity on the size of the final list. Instead, `extend` is amoratized O(B) where B is the size of the smaller list, so it is O(N) on the size of the final list.

Comment: A list of lists

[[a, b, c], [b, c, d]...]

Comment: @cjm2671, Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: It looks like you just want to flatten your list of lists, in that case: `from itertools import chain; x = list(chain.from_iterable(c))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Running some minimal tests, `+=` runs approximately 20-30% faster than `extend`. So I'd be surprised if they are doing the same thing.

Comment: += runs in about 4 seconds. Compared to 10 minutes, I consider this to be a real victory.

Comment: @PMende they are doing the same thing. `+=` is just faster because the interpreter doesn't have to resole `c.extend`, attribute access is slow, `+=` will shortcut it

Comment: @cjm2671 try `list(chain.from_iterable(c))`, should be the fastest

Comment: list(chain.from_iterable(c)) = 3.51 seconds - that's the winner!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Makes sense. Thanks! Looks like `+=` and `chain.from_iterable` are the fastest of the options.

Comment: Would you mind using latest version of pypy? It is said to be generally alot faster than cpython implementation. Try it and see for yourself if it is so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088089/python-list-concatenation-efficiency

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why not post your answer as...well...an answer? The question asks how to accelerate the computation: so your answer is definitely valid...admittedly there are *many* answers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Already compared in [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

with Python 2 being faster with .extend than with itertools.chain

An exotique method

```
l = [] 
for x in c: l[0:0] = x
```

among the faster according to
stackoverflow.com/questions/12088089/…

For python 3.5 and latter, even more exotic

```
l = [] 
for x in c: 
    l = [l, *x]
```

Of course sum(c, []) is among worst on all the measurements.