# Python - 'append' VS '+=' efficiency

Tags: python, list

I need to iterate over a large dataset, and store my results in a list. This is the code:

```
results = []
n=10000    
for i in range(1,n):
    text = requests.get("""https://www.chess.com/games/archive/eono619gameOwner=other_game&gameTypes%5B0%5D=chess960&gameTypes%5B1%5D=daily&gameType=live&page{}""".format(i)).text
    result = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
```

now for populating my list, I can do:

```
   results += result
```

or:

```
   results.append(result)
```

is any option more efficient for dealing with large datasets? if so, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python append() vs. + operator on lists, why do these give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)

Comment: `+=` is like *extend*, not append.

Comment: This may help [python list concatenation efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088089/python-list-concatenation-efficiency).  Shows timing performance of different methods.

Comment: You might also want to consider using a generator, if there's no strict need to actually accumulate the results.

Comment: @IainShelvington no, it does not. It modifies the list in-place, and is essentially equivalent to `.extend`

Comment: @DataGarden those two do different things, but they are both equally efficient (and as efficient as you will get).

Comment: @IainShelvington No, `+=` updates the list in-place. Augmented assignment operators were introduced precisely to provide an in-place option, since `results = results + result` necessarily creates a new list first.

Comment: The two operations do completely different things in this context. Please fix your question to account for that.

Comment: Funny. The question opens a discussion of 20 comments, the accepted answer is upvoted twice, but still the question gets 3 downvotes. the downvoter logic sometimes eludes me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension instead.

```
url = "https://www.chess.com/games/archive/eono619"
params = {
  'gameOwner': 'other_game',
  'gameTypes[0]': 'chess',
  'gameTypes[1]': 'daily',
  'gameType': 'live'
}
results = [BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params={**params, 'page': i}).text, 'html.parser') for i in range(1,n)]
```

though that's pushing it in terms of complexity. (Also, you don't have the opportunity to check that your request succeeded before trying to parse the response with BeautifulSoup). Otherwise, use `append`.

```
results = []
for i in range(1,n):
    response = requests.get(url, params={**params, 'page': i})
    # TODO Make sure you got a 200 response first
    result = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    results.append(result)
```

Comment: Nice. Especially since the list is of fixed length

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `results += result` is *not* equivalent to `results.append(result)`. It just happens to work because `result` is iterable, but will effectively flatten all your object together. Put another way, `+=` is a somewhat more restricted equivalent of `list.extend`, not `list.append`. The latter is much closer to `results += [result]`, which is clearly less efficient.

Since you have a fixed number of objects, a list comprehension, as suggested by [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59595296/2988730) is perfectly fine.

For cases that have a variable number of objects being generated, I'd recommend a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with a generator expression. This is especially important for long sequences. Appending to a `list` is amortized to have long-term `O(n)` reallocation behavior, but it's a slow `O(n)`, and pretty bad in the short term. `deques` are much faster than that, and can be turned into a list with a single allocation as soon as the length is known.

```
from collections import deque

template = 'https://www.chess.com/games/archive/eono619?gameOwner=other_game&gameTypes%5B0%5D=chess960&gameTypes%5B1%5D=daily&gameType=live&page={}'
results = deque(BeautifulSoup(template.format(i), 'html.parser') for i in range(1, n))
results = list(results)
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann. That's probably because the object is iterable. The list will *not* be equivalent to the appended one that way.

Comment: @StefanPochmann. That being said, thanks for the catch: I fixed the answer to include.

Comment: Do you have an example of `deque` being faster? I'd find that surprising, and I just did a test, `[x for x in range(1000000)]` was about factor 1.5 faster than `deque(x for x in range(1000000))`.

Comment: I also tried `[x for x in X if x]` and `deque(x for x in X if x)` with `X = [random.choice((True, False)) for _ in range(1000000)]` and again the list comprehension was much faster.

Comment: @StefanPochman. I don't think deque will ever be faster for an iterable that supports `len` (or actually a proper `__len_hint__`), regardless of the condition, since a list comprehension can always preallocate the upper bound. Make `X` into a generator and see if there's a difference (replace `[]` with `()`, and don't forget to reinitialize between runs).

Comment: @MadPhysicist list comprehensions don't preallocate ever. they always just use `.append `under the hood. In any case, appending to the end of a list will be faster than a deque, but slower at the beginning.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok I tried `[x for x in g() if x]` and `deque(x for x in g() if x)` with `def g(): for x in X: yield x`, and list comprehension was still much faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'm not sure I understand why. deques don't need to copy data/reallocate. Is it because the default block size is small enough that the frequent allocations dominate once the list size goes up sufficiently?

Comment: @Stefan. Thanks for running the tests and educating me. I'm not near a desktop atm, so doubly appreciate it. I'll delete this answer as soon as I understand why it's so wrong.